# Extract text from webpage with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am attempting to extract IP addresses from a webpage using the following code (snippet).

```
IPs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '10.')]")
print(IPs)
```

The HTML element(s) look like this:

```
<span style="padding: 1px 4px;float:left;">10.20.20.20</span>
```

Inspect >> Copy Xpath returns:

```
//*[@id="T1700010887"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/nobr/span
```

But all my code prints is what looks like generic selenium code:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7885f3a61de714f2cb33
b23d03112ff2", element="0.5496921740104628-2")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webe
lement.WebElement (session="7885f3a61de714f2cb33b23d03112ff2", element="0.549692
1740104628-3")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7885
f3a61de714f2cb33b23d03112ff2", element="0.5496921740104628-4")>]
```

How can I get it to print the actual IP of 10.20.20.20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Selenium's element finding methods, you're retrieving a [WebElement](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) object. What you want is the element's text, which you can retrieve via the `text` attribute of your WebElement object. Also, the `find_elements_by_xpath` method returns a list of WebElements, so you need to iterate it:

```
IPs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '10.')]")

for ip in IPs:
    print(ip.text)
```

Comment: Excellent explanation and works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`find_elements_by_xpath` returns a list of selenium objects. You have to access to each object's text attribute. This code should do what you want:

```
IPs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '10.')]")
IPS = [elem.text for elem in IPs]
print(IPs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `text()`

```
IPs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '10.')]/text()")
```